# How to use order by preserving result returned after group by clause

Tags: sql-server

I am facing problem in query result in which if i use `order by` on resultset returned after `group by` , the grouping order is disturbed .

```
select a.location_id,a.feed_date 
  from p_article_table
  inner join m_misc_details l on a.location_id = l.misc_detail_id 
   and misc_master_id=2 
   and a.location_id in (1,2,4,5,6,7,8)
   and  convert(varchar(11),a.feed_date,108)<'09:01:00'
group by a.location_id,a.feed_date 
order by a.feed_date
```

What should I do ?

The result after GROUP BY on location_id gives

```
1   
1
1
1
5
7
7
7
8
```

But after I use ORDER BY on feed_date , the result gets disturbed

1
1
5
7
1
8
1
..

Comment: what data do you want to get back?  what data do you currently get back?  what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grouping operation is not affected by order by. The order that the grouped records are returned withoout an order by is arbitrary.

Did you want this:

```
select a.location_id,a.feed_date 
  from p_article_table
  inner join m_misc_details l on a.location_id = l.misc_detail_id 
   and misc_master_id=2 
   and a.location_id in (1,2,4,5,6,7,8)
   and  convert(varchar(11),a.feed_date,108)<'09:01:00'
group by a.location_id, a.feed_date 
order by a.location_id, a.feed_date
```